# mysqli does not select the proper data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this fiddle file http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78b31/20 tho the issue i face is that i wont now just not Display the right data.

For eg. when i try date = 2018-01-24 for the 3rd data (C) is still showing up.

later on i would like to then have the date updated with this function date:

```
$date = ("Y-m-d");.
```

so that it would only Show the `bowCode /BowID` which have not been inserted into comeandtradaysparticipant

Comment: Could you please format your question? I suggest to remove typos, highlight the code, and remove things like "tho".

Comment: Is there any PHP code involved that you forgot to share?

Comment: I suspect that your `LEFT JOIN` should actually be an `INNER JOIN` though it's quite hard to understand exactly what you're after

Comment: @NicoHaase the function i have included is also php so i wasnt quite sure

Comment: @RobForrest i have just tired inner join but then it wont Display any values. sorry for making it Sound so complicated

Comment: A fiddle is fine as a bonus, but the question itself needs to contain all necessary information, otherwise it'll eventually become useless.

Comment: Did you intend to have `rcx03` in `equipment` and a similar but different `rcx003` in `comeandtrydaysparticipant`?

Comment: Hi Rob Thank you for spotting this small error.

Comment: @deceze ok fair enough. but as you can maybe see im quite new to here so i didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a LEFT JOIN. What you are looking for is a simple JOIN.
LEFT JOIN retrieve the data of the joined table if the ON condition is correct, otherwise it return null values.

If you try to display a.date you will see that with the LEFT JOIN it will be NULL values.

```
 SELECT 
       b.id, b.BowCode, b.Info, a.date
    FROM Equipment AS b
    JOIN comeandtrydaysparticipant AS a
             ON a.BowID = b.BowCode
    WHERE a.BowID IS NULL
    OR(a.BowID=b.BowCode AND a.date<>"2018-01-27");

    SELECT 
       b.id, b.BowCode, b.Info, a.date
    FROM Equipment AS b
    JOIN comeandtrydaysparticipant AS a
             ON a.BowID = b.BowCode
    WHERE a.BowID IS NULL
    OR(a.BowID=b.BowCode AND a.date <> "2018-01-24");
```